# Min value of array with max criteria

Tags: arrays, sas

I am currently sourcing data in SAS EG 6.1 to get the min and max values based on the observation.  Now I need to be able to grab the minimum value out of an array where only included in the array are numbers >= 90.

```
data MinMaxRows;
set tbl4;
where EvalDt1 <> .;
array x(3) date1-date3;
max_value=max(of x(*));
min_value=min(of x(*));
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the 'manual' way...ie search through the array.

```
data want;
set tbl4;
array crit(3) crit1-crit3;
array date(3) date1-date3;

crit_max90=.;
crit_index90=.;
do i=1 to dim(crit);
if crit(i)>90 and crit(i)>crit_max90 then do;
    crit_max90=crit(i);
    crit_index90=i;
end;
end;

run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to create another array with your criteria of 90 that corresponds to the date. This is what I'm envisioning your data looking like:

```
data &wl.tbl4;
infile datalines;
input @1 date1 mmddyy10. 
      @10 date2 mmddyy10. 
      @19 date3 mmddyy10. 
      @28 Evaldt1 mmddyy10. 
      @37 crit1 
      @40 crit2 
      @43 crit3;
format date1--evaldt1 mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1/1/2016 1/2/2016 1/3/2016 1/1/2016 85 90 95
;
run;
```

And this is what you would use to apply that criteria to your array:

```
data MinMaxRows;
set tbl4;
where EvalDt1 <> .;
array x(3) date1-date3;
array x_90(3) _temporary_;
array crit(3) crit1-crit3;
do i = 1 to 3;
    if crit(i) >= 90 then x_90(i) = x(i);
end;
format max_value min_value max_value_90 min_value_90 mmddyy10.;
max_value=max(of x(*));
min_value=min(of x(*));
max_value_90=max(of x_90(*));
min_value_90=min(of x_90(*));
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with a single function, you can always use FCMP (in 9.4+, I think 9.3 it won't accept a non-temporary array):

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.func;
  function minMin(min,num[*]);
    curMin = constant('BIG');
    do _i = 1 to dim(num);
      if num[_i] ge min and num[_i] lt curMin then
        curMin = num[_i];
    end;

    if curMin < constant('BIG') then 
      return(curMin);
    else return(.);

  endsub;
quit;
options cmplib=work.funcs;

data test;
  array x[3];
  x[1]=4;
  x[2]=11;
  x[3]=15;
  x_min=min(of x[*]);
  x_min_10 = minMin(10,x);
  put x_min= x_min_10=;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop any values less than 90, then perform the `min()` and `max()` :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array dt{*} date1-date3 ;
  do i = 1 to dim(dt) ;
    dt{i} = ifn(dt{i} < 90 , . , dt{i}) ;
  end ;
  dtmax = max(of dt:) ;
  dtmin = min(of dt:) ;
run ;
```

Comment: Seems rather destructive, doesn't it?